# (VB.NET) Quick way for a Simple Splashscreen for WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, splash-screen

My program took ~5-10 seconds to load and sometimes people using it would end up trying to open it again, which caused problems. I found a quick and easy way to make a "splashscreen" (in a sense) that pops up for a set amount of time immediately on execution. I found that the first order of events in a WinForm EXE loading was `Handle Created`. The answer is not a *true* splashscreen, but for a couple lines of code that can be easily added to a project, I think some people will like it.

Comment: Set the SplashScreen in [designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/application-page-project-designer-visual-basic?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#splash-screen) or in [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.splashscreen?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Comment: Why don't you open your mainform without executing any code, so it appears immediate, and then start doing your lengthy code. Then you don't need a splash screen.

Comment: If it's a problem for a Windows Forms program to be opened more than once, you can check the "Make single instance application" setting in the project's properties.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will show a MessageBox immediately on running the EXE and closes after 10 seconds.

```
Imports System.Threading

Private Sub Control1_HandleCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.HandleCreated
    Dim SplashScreen As New Thread(
        Sub()
            CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup("Program Initializing, Please Wait...",10, "Setup Tool")
        End Sub)
    SplashScreen.Start()
End Sub
```

I use Threading so that the MessageBox will not freeze the code and the program will open with or without the OK button being pressed. Doing a regular `MessageBox.Show()` will prevent any more code from running until the user clicks OK I have found.

Comment: Just use the splash screen functionality already built into WinForms. Simply select a form as the splash screen in the project properties and it will be displayed for at least 2 seconds or until the startup form displays. The splash screen form is created and displayed on a secondary thread automatically.

Comment: Consider enabling [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) which will result in a compiler error when using the code above. It helps to ensure that one uses good programming practices.

Comment: Can you give more detailed instructions on the actual splash screen? A nice floating logo that appears for a couple seconds might be nice but no sense in making a new window/form popup since my HandleCreated messagebox works fine. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to implement a splash screen which keeps the user informed via messages and/or a progress bar or animated wheel is the following.

Have a startup form eg Form1, and have it carry out all the tedious startup procedures which might cause any animated or progress bar graphic to get stalled in the event queue. Add a "BackgroundWorker" object to Form1 from the Toolbox and in my case I just named it BackgroundWorker1.

Before starting these routines, usually in the Form1_Load event, make a call to the BackgroundWorker.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        
        CallBackgroundWork()

        StartRoutines() 'this is the heavy lifting routines to get the app working. Set the LoadingStatusflag (declared as a Global Variable"
to various values to tell the splashscreen to display different messages

        Loadingstatus = 10 'triggers splashform to exit
        CancelBackgroundWork()

    End Sub
```

These are the other subs to support this

```
Sub CallBackgroundWork()

        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True

        ' call this method to start your asynchronous Task.
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

    End Sub

    Sub CancelBackgroundWork()

        ' to cancel the task, just call the BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync method.

        BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()

    End Sub

    Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        '' The asynchronous task we want to perform goes here
        FormSplash.Show()

    End Sub
```

My splashscreen has some label controls and pictureboxes and the FormSplash_Load event runs a stopwatch loop of 40ms and loads a series of images (24 in total) of a spinning wheel. This keeps running while the splashscreen is active. By setting the global variable Loadingstatus to various values within different part of the loading sequence in Form1 it can trigger the loop routine to display different messages example shown. An easy way to communicate between threads as you can't directly access objects between threads The wheel keeps spinning no matter how intensive the load routine in Form1 as it is running in another thread. I used a stopwatch loop as starting a timer doesn't work for me - maybe an event queue issue in splash form.

```
Private Sub FormSplash_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        Me.Show()

        Me.Opacity = 1  'show this form

        'now start a loop that gets ended by other thread through variable Loadingstatus flag
        Dim ggtimer As New Stopwatch, lastvalue As Integer, FProgPosition as integer

        ggtimer.Start()
        lastvalue = ggtimer.ElapsedMilliseconds

nextimage:
        FProgPosition += 1
        If FProgPosition = 24 Then FProgPosition = 1 'has 24 frames in the animated image

        Do  'loop for 40 ms
            If ggtimer.ElapsedMilliseconds - lastvalue > 40 Then
                lastvalue = ggtimer.ElapsedMilliseconds
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        PictureBoxProgress1.Image = FProgIMG(FProgPosition)
        PictureBoxProgress1.Refresh()

        If Loadingstatus = 10 Then GoTo endsplash

        If Loadingstatus = 1 Then

            If CoreTempRunning = False Then
                Me.LabelCoreTemp.Text = "CoreTemp is NOT Running"
                Me.LabelCoreTemp.ForeColor = Color.White
                'insert cross picturebox
                PictureBoxCoreTemp.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Cross24x24")
                loaderrorflag2 = True
            Else
                Me.LabelCoreTemp.Text = "CoreTemp is Running"
                Me.LabelCoreTemp.ForeColor = Color.White
                'insert tick picturebox
                PictureBoxCoreTemp.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Tick24x24")
                loaderrorflag2 = False
            End If
            Me.PictureBoxCoreTemp.Visible = True
            Me.PictureBoxCoreTemp.Refresh()

            Me.LabelCoreTemp.Left = Me.Width * 2 / 3 - Me.LabelCoreTemp.Width
            Me.LabelCoreTemp.Refresh()


        GoTo nextimage
endsplash:

        ggtimer.Stop()
        Me.Opacity = 0.01
        Me.Hide()

    End Sub
```